# How to disable reCAPTCHA Flask App Builder

Tags: flask, recaptcha, flask-wtforms

I am new to flask app builder and am trying to set up user registration but for my purposes, I do not need reCAPTCHA.  Is there a way to disable reCaptcha in the config file?  Here is what my config file looks like below:

```
# Uncomment to setup Public role name, no authentication needed
# AUTH_ROLE_PUBLIC = 'Public'

# Will allow user self registration
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True

# Config for Flask-WTF Recaptcha necessary for user registration
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = 'GOOGLE PUBLIC KEY FOR RECAPTCHA'
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = 'GOOGLE PRIVATE KEY FOR RECAPTCHA'
# Config for Flask-Mail necessary for user registration
MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
MAIL_USE_TLS = True
MAIL_USERNAME = 'yourappemail@gmail.com'
MAIL_PASSWORD = 'passwordformail'
MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER = 'fabtest10@gmail.com'


# The default user self registration role
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Public"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the recaptcha feature and bypass validation, you will need to set `RECAPTCHA_ENABLED = False`

> RECAPTCHA_ENABLED: Bool - True by default, when False it will bypass validation

Future calls to recaptcha.verify() in your flask server file will return True by default as a result.

To disable and hide the recaptcha in the HTML template code, simply omit any code with `{{ recaptcha }}`  in your form.

Found from the documentation here: https://github.com/mardix/flask-recaptcha

Comment: Thank you!  Would I make this change in the config file for flask app builder?  Would that work as well or is this strictly a flask configuration and it needs to be at the lower level?  Where is the config file for the flask section if I can't just change the flask app builder config file?

Comment: As long as it’s in the config it can be anywhere. There’s an example here https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-use-google-recaptcha-with-flask-dbd79d5ea193 that shows adding keys to a config. It’s fairly standard.

Comment: Not exactly sure how the builder works, but it probably just generates a python file and does the same function as hard coding it manually. The config for flask always works off the same key-value system.