# How are I disable the RECAPTCHA on Flask appbuilder?

Tags: flask, recaptcha, flask-appbuilder

Due to school asignment, I have to write a wedsite with flask appbuilder, when I try to add a register page, I don't need the RECAPTCHA.

So, how can I disable this?

I tried:
add `RECAPTCHA_ENABLED = False` in config.py  ---  [not working, the RECAPTCHA fleid still there]

Comment: Already answered here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70725782/how-to-disable-recaptcha-flask-app-builder#:~:text=Future%20calls%20to%20recaptcha.,recaptcha%20%7D%7D%20in%20your%20form.&text=As%20long%20as%20it's%20in%20the%20config%20it%20can%20be%20anywhere.